# Android, Visual Studio, Xamarin: Bitmap is null when in release mode, but != null when in debug mode

Tags: android, visual-studio

This is the problem:

```
try {
 if (bitmap == null) // app crashes without any error message in release
 {
  width = 100; //bitmap.Width;
  height = 200; //bitmap.Height;
  Toast.MakeText(this, "bitmap was null", ToastLength.Short).Show();
 }
 else {
  width = bitmap.Width;
  height = bitmap.Height;
 }
} catch {
 Toast.MakeText(this, "bitmap was not null", ToastLength.Short).Show();
}
```

Out of the blue our app started crashing when the user was to take a picture and then edit this. But whenever we would debug this error, it wouldn't appear. Now, after many try and catches I narrowed it down. For some reason, the bitmap is null when the app is in release mode. But In the debug mode, the bitmap returns an object and therefore the app doesn't crash.

Also interesting: the app crashes even though the code that is supposed to make it crash gets skipped. BUT the android OS doesn't say "app crashed" it just ends the app. No error message as before when without the try catch blocks.

Would anyone know what the problem could be?

Thanks in Advance!.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have ALL the permissions in your manifest that you need and maybe even a few more, just to be sure.

I don't know why my app couldn't just tell me in debug mode that some vital permissions are missing, but hey - that's 5 hours well wasted.